# keep tracking time in while loop and interacting with other commands in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, time, while-loop

So i created a while loop that the user input and an output is returned

```
choice = input()
while True:
    if choice == "Mark":
       print("Zuckerberg")
    elif choice == "Sundar":
       print("Pichai")
```

and i want to keep time so when i hit Facebook is going to keep time for FB and when i type Google is going to keep time for google like this

```
import time
choice = input()
while True:
    if choice == "Facebook":
       endb = time.time()
       starta = time.time()
    if choice == "google":
       enda = time.time()
       startb = time.time()
    if choice == "Mark":
       print("Zuckerberg")
    elif choice == "Sundar":
       print("Pichai")
```

if i make this like above when i get to print the elapsed time is going to print
the same number but is going to be minus instead of plus, and vice versa

```
elapseda = enda - starta
elapsedb = endb - startb
print(elapseda)
print(elapsedb)
```

How do i keep track of the time but be able to interact with my other input/outputs?

Thanks

##############################################################################

Edit: Sorry for making it not clear. What i meant by tracking time it that instead of print an output when you type a keyword is going to track time. This will be used to take the possession time of a sport match but meanwhile count other stats like Penalty Kicks and stuff. I cant post my code due to character limit but here is an idea:

```
while True:
   choice = input()
   if choice == "pk":
      print("pk")
   elif choice == "fk":
      print("fk")
   elif choice == "q":
      break
```

and in there i should put possession time but meanwhile i want to interact with the others

Comment: Where does the while loop end?

Comment: I didn't quite get what's the desired behavior. What is the elapsed time you're trying to measure?

Comment: Can be more specific? What do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry i was out... the loop ends when the user enters q

Comment: this is an example, the program will be to count possession time in sports

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop you could count seconds like so.

```
import time
a = 0
while True:
    a = a + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

That would mean that a is about how many seconds it look to do the while loop.